# Why does IE block its own script for collapsing XML tags?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, xml

Every time I open an XML file in IE (I know, right?), I get the yellow bar security error saying scripts are blocked. Allowing the script to run makes it so you can collapse tags. Seems a bit superfluous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only see this for local files. It also applies to any other JavaScript, such as used in local HTML files.

Apparently, when allowing JavaScript for local files, one is granting JavaScript access to the whole local file system. (Which is not the case for JavaScript that is executed for some website.) Hence: IE will ask you if you're sure.

Comment: Fair enough. Still can't shake the feeling there's room for improvement though (e.g. directly implementing this feature in IE or having some sort of trusted locations for scripts)